# Should I use freeze for ActiveSupport::Duration objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I define some constants with duration

```rb
EXAMPLE_DAYS = 12.days
```

it will not be frozen

```
> EXAMPLE_DAYS.frozen?
false
```

And in ruboсop there are no corresponding rules.

Is it necessary to freeze constants with such objects at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the type of object you assign to the constant. For an instance of [`ActiveSupport::Duration`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html) it doesn't really make sense to freeze it, because it doesn't have any public writer method that allows changing it. But you still can, when you want to please Rubocop.

```
DAYS = 12.days.freeze
DAYS.frozen?
#=> true
```

For other object like, for example, a string it absolutely makes sense to freeze them, because they can change when it is not frozen and you usually want constants not to change.

```
STRING = 'string'
STRING[1..4] = '----'
STRING
#=> "s----g"
```

But when frozen:

```
STRING = 'string'.freeze
STRING[1..4] = '----'
#=> `[]=': can't modify frozen String: "string" (FrozenError)
```

Comment: I wish Ruby has JS like `const` when declaring the constant variables. :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit not exactly the same thing `const` merely prevents reassignment, not mutation.

Comment: @engineersmnky hm true.